# How to reduce the number of iterations in a program where number of elements in the test case is very large?

Tags: java

Please refer to this [problem from Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fraudulent-activity-notifications/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=sorting&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen)

HackerLand National Bank has a simple policy for warning clients about possible fraudulent account activity. If the amount spent by a client on a particular day is greater than or equal to the client's median spending for a trailing number of days, they send the client a notification about potential fraud. The bank doesn't send the client any notifications until they have at least that trailing number of prior days' transaction data.

I have written the following code. However, the code is working for some of the test cases and is getting 'terminated due to timeout' for some. Can anyone please tell how can I improve the code?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    // Complete the activityNotifications function below.
    static int activityNotifications(int[] expenditure, int d)     {
        //Delaring Variables

        int iterations,itr,length,median,midDummy,midL,midR,               midDummy2,i,i1,temp,count;
        float mid,p,q;
        length = expenditure.length;
        iterations = length-d;
        i=0;
        i1=0;
        itr=0;
        count = 0;

        int[] exSub = new int[d];

        while(iterations>0)
        {

            // Enter the elements in the subarray
            while(i1<d)
            {
                exSub[i1]=expenditure[i+i1];
                //System.out.println(exSub[i1]);
                i1++;
            }

            //Sort the exSub array
            for(int k=0; k<(d-1); k++)
            {
                for(int j=k+1; j<d; j++)
                {
                    if(exSub[j]<exSub[k])
                    {
                        temp = exSub[j];
                        exSub[j] = exSub[k];
                        exSub[k] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Printing the exSub array in each iteration


            for(int l = 0 ; l<d ; l++)
            {
                System.out.println(exSub[l]);
            }


            i1=0;


            //For each iteration claculate the median

            if(d%2 == 0) // even
            {
                midDummy = d/2;
                p= (float)exSub[midDummy];
                q= (float)exSub[midDummy-1];  
                mid = (p+q)/2;                            
                //mid = (exSub[midDummy]+exSub                                   [midDummy-1])/2;
                //System.out.println(midDummy);
            }
            else // odd
            {

                midDummy2 =d/2;
                mid=exSub[midDummy2];
                //System.out.println(midDummy2);
            }

            if(expenditure[itr+d]>=2*mid)
            {
                count++;
            }
            itr++;
            i++;
            iterations--;

            System.out.println("Mid:"+mid);
            System.out.println("---------");

        }

        System.out.println("Count:"+count);
        return count;

    }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        String[] nd = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        int n = Integer.parseInt(nd[0]);

        int d = Integer.parseInt(nd[1]);

        int[] expenditure = new int[n];

        String[] expenditureItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int expenditureItem = Integer.parseInt(expenditureItems[i]);
            expenditure[i] = expenditureItem;
        }

        int result = activityNotifications(expenditure, d);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedWriter.close();

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In any case, you need a data structure which allows one to quickly find a median. In general you would need a hand-written TreeMultiSet, which is a bit of pain. But here you are saved by constraint `expenditure[i] < 200`: you can use bitset-like approach (and have the total time `n * 200`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule on performance improvement is: **Don't improve the performance if it's not needed**.

Performance improvements usually lead to code that is less readable and therefore it should only be done when it's really needed.

The second rule is: **Improve algorithms and data-structures before low-level improvements**.

If you need to improve the performance of your code always try to use more efficient algorithms and data-structures before going to low-level improvement. In your code example that would be: Don't use [BubbleSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), but try to use more efficient algorithms like [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) or [Mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), because they use time complexity of `O(n*log(n)` while Bubble sort has a time complexity of `O(n^2)` which is much slower when you have to sort big arrays. You can use [Arrays.sort(int[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) to do this.

Your data-structures are only arrays so this can't be improved in your code.

This will give your code quite some speedup, and will not lead to a code that can't be read anymore. Improvements like changing simple calculations to slightly faster calculations using bitshifts and other fast calculations (that are pretty hard to understand if used to often) will almost always lead to a code that is only slightly faster but no one will be able to easily understand it anymore.

Some improvements that could be applied to your code (that will also only slightly improve the performance) are:

- Replace `while` loops with `for` loops if possible (they can be improved by the compiler)
- Don't use `System.out.println` for many texts if it's not totaly needed (because it's quite slow for big texts)
- Try to copy arrays using [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) which usually is faster than copying using while loops

So an improved code of yours could look like this (I marked the changed parts with comments):

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    // Complete the activityNotifications function below.
    static int activityNotifications(int[] expenditure, int d) {
        //Delaring Variables

        int iterations, itr, length, median, midDummy, midL, midR, midDummy2, i, i1, temp, count;
        float mid, p, q;
        length = expenditure.length;
        iterations = length - d;
        i = 0;
        i1 = 0;
        itr = 0;
        count = 0;

        int[] exSub = new int[d];

        //EDIT: replace while loops with for loops if possible
        //while (iterations > 0) { 
        for (int iter = 0; iter < iterations; iter++) {

            //EDIT: here you can again use a for loop or just use System.arraycopy which should be (slightly) fasters
            // Enter the elements in the subarray
            /*while (i1 < d) {
                exSub[i1] = expenditure[i + i1];
                //System.out.println(exSub[i1]);
                i1++;
            }*/
            System.arraycopy(expenditure, i, exSub, 0, d);

            //EDIT: Don't use bubble sort!!! It's one of the worst sorting algorithms, because it's really slow
            //Bubble sort uses time complexity O(n^2); others (like merge-sort or quick-sort) only use O(n*log(n))
            //The easiest and fastest solution is: don't implement sorting by yourself, but use Arrays.sort(int[]) from the java API

            //Sort the exSub array
            /*for (int k = 0; k < (d - 1); k++) {
                for (int j = k + 1; j < d; j++) {
                    if (exSub[j] < exSub[k]) {
                        temp = exSub[j];
                        exSub[j] = exSub[k];
                        exSub[k] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }*/
            Arrays.sort(exSub);


            //Printing the exSub array in each iteration

            //EDIT: printing many results also takes much time, so only print the results if it's really needed

            /*for (int l = 0; l < d; l++) {
                System.out.println(exSub[l]);
            }*/

            i1 = 0;

            //For each iteration claculate the median

            if (d % 2 == 0) // even
            {
                midDummy = d / 2;
                p = (float) exSub[midDummy];
                q = (float) exSub[midDummy - 1];
                mid = (p + q) / 2;
                //mid = (exSub[midDummy]+exSub                                   [midDummy-1])/2;
                //System.out.println(midDummy);
            }
            else // odd
            {

                midDummy2 = d / 2;
                mid = exSub[midDummy2];
                //System.out.println(midDummy2);
            }

            if (expenditure[itr + d] >= 2 * mid) {
                count++;
            }
            itr++;
            i++;
            //iterations--;//EDIT: don't change iterations anymore because of the for loop

            System.out.println("Mid:" + mid);
            System.out.println("---------");

        }

        System.out.println("Count:" + count);
        return count;

    }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        String[] nd = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        int n = Integer.parseInt(nd[0]);

        int d = Integer.parseInt(nd[1]);

        int[] expenditure = new int[n];

        String[] expenditureItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int expenditureItem = Integer.parseInt(expenditureItems[i]);
            expenditure[i] = expenditureItem;
        }

        int result = activityNotifications(expenditure, d);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedWriter.close();

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

You can make the solution even faster if you don't sort the complete (sub-)array in every iteration, but instead only remove one value (the first day that is not used anymore) and add a new value (the new day that is now used) in the correct position (like @Vojtěch Kaiser mentioned in his answer)

This will make it even faster, because sorting an array takes the time `O(d*log(d))`, while adding a new value into an array, that is already sorted only takes the time `O(log(d))` if you are using a search tree. When using an array (like I did in the example below) it takes the time `O(d)` because when using an array you need to copy the array values which takes linear time (like @dyukha mentioned in the comments). So the improvement (again) can be done by using a better algorithm (This solution could also be improved by using a search tree instead of an array).

So the new solution could look like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    // Complete the activityNotifications function below.
    static int activityNotifications(int[] expenditure, int d) {
        //Delaring Variables

        int iterations, length, midDummy, midDummy2, count;//EDIT: removed some unused variables here
        float mid, p, q;
        length = expenditure.length;
        iterations = length - d;
        count = 0;

        //EDIT: add the first d values to the sub-array and sort it (only once)
        int[] exSub = new int[d];
        System.arraycopy(expenditure, 0, exSub, 0, d);
        Arrays.sort(exSub);

        for (int iter = 0; iter < iterations; iter++) {
            //EDIT: don't sort the complete array in every iteration
            //instead remove the one value (the first day that is not used anymore) and add the new value (of the new day) into the sorted array
            //sorting is done in O(n * log(n)); deleting and inserting a new value into a sorted array is done in O(log(n))

            if (iter > 0) {//not for the first iteration
                int remove = expenditure[iter - 1];
                int indexToRemove = find(exSub, remove);
                //remove the index and move the following values one index to the left
                exSub[indexToRemove] = 0;//not needed; just to make it more clear what's happening
                System.arraycopy(exSub, indexToRemove + 1, exSub, indexToRemove, exSub.length - indexToRemove - 1);
                exSub[d - 1] = 0;//not needed again; just to make it more clear what's happening

                int newValue = expenditure[iter + d - 1];
                //insert the new value to the correct position
                insertIntoSortedArray(exSub, newValue);
            }

            //For each iteration claculate the median
            if (d % 2 == 0) // even
            {
                midDummy = d / 2;
                p = exSub[midDummy];
                q = exSub[midDummy - 1];
                mid = (p + q) / 2;
                //mid = (exSub[midDummy]+exSub                                   [midDummy-1])/2;
                //System.out.println(midDummy);
            }
            else // odd
            {

                midDummy2 = d / 2;
                mid = exSub[midDummy2];
                //System.out.println(midDummy2);
            }

            if (expenditure[iter + d] >= 2 * mid) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Count:" + count);
        return count;

    }

    /**
     * Find the position of value in expenditure
     */
    private static int find(int[] array, int value) {
        int index = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == value) {
                index = i;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }

    /**
     * Find the correct position to insert value into the array by bisection search
     */
    private static void insertIntoSortedArray(int[] array, int value) {
        int[] indexRange = new int[] {0, array.length - 1};
        while (indexRange[1] - indexRange[0] > 0) {
            int mid = indexRange[0] + (indexRange[1] - indexRange[0]) / 2;
            if (value > array[mid]) {
                if (mid == indexRange[0]) {
                    indexRange[0] = mid + 1;
                }
                else {
                    indexRange[0] = mid;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (mid == indexRange[1]) {
                    indexRange[1] = mid - 1;
                }
                else {
                    indexRange[1] = mid;
                }
            }
        }

        System.arraycopy(array, indexRange[0], array, indexRange[0] + 1, array.length - indexRange[0] - 1);
        array[indexRange[0]] = value;
    }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        String[] nd = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        int n = Integer.parseInt(nd[0]);

        int d = Integer.parseInt(nd[1]);

        int[] expenditure = new int[n];

        String[] expenditureItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int expenditureItem = Integer.parseInt(expenditureItems[i]);
            expenditure[i] = expenditureItem;
        }

        int result = activityNotifications(expenditure, d);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedWriter.close();

        scanner.close();

        //Just for testing; can be deleted if you don't need it
        /*int[] exp = new int[] {2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 6, 8, 4, 5};
        int d = 5;
        activityNotifications(exp, d);

        int[] exp2 = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 4};
        d = 4;
        activityNotifications(exp2, d);*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have tried running the program in hackerranck but it still shows timeout for few of the test cases. Can you please suggest a way so that the intermediate array need not be created. Thanks. Please keep the code you've written. Thanks for your insight and help.

Comment: I edited the answer. Now the code should be running faster.

Comment: `adding a new value into an array, that is already sorted only takes the time O(log(d))` that's incorrect (if it was that simple, people wouldn't need search trees). `System.arraycopy` takes linear time.

Comment: @dyukha You're right. I forgot about the linear time for System.arraycopy. I'll edit that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your main concern is that you are sorting the partial array in every iteration, costing you total complexity of the problem *O(n d log(d))*, which can get pretty hairy for large *d* values.

What you want is to keep the array sorted between iterations and sort in/out changed values. For that you would implement binary search tree (BST) or some other balanced option (AVL, ...), perform *O(log(d))* removal of oldest value, then perform *O(log(d))* insertion of new value, and simply look in the middle for median. Total asymptotic complexity would be *O(n log(d))* which is as far as I know the best you can get - rest of the optimization is low level dirty work.

Take a look at java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html, which should take care of the most of the work, but keep in mind that underlying structure is made out of objects that will be slower than arrays.

Comment: So, you suggest that I should not use the intermediate array. Instead, I should use Binary Search Tree that would reduce complexity?

Comment: Yes, a search tree that carries over all iterations instead of array you resort in each iteration.